# Selenium: access element using span class name

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

I have this very complicated `xpath`:

```
/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/input
```

The span has this `class="z-combobox-designation z-combobox"`.

I need to access the `span` element using its `class` and not through `xpath`. Is it possible with `cssSelector`? Can someone give me a hint how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use css selector in this way to select your element based on compound classes

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".z-combobox-designation.z-combobox"));
```

or specify the tag name with classes like `span.z-combobox-designation.z-combobox`

If you have same kind of element more then one in your HTML  then  consider the unique parent of it and locate the same

E.g. there is parent `table` of your element which have unique id e.g. so you can consider that table tag fist and locate `span` based on that table e.g.

```
table#someid span.z-combobox-designation.z-combobox
```

Comment: I think it works, it didn't result in any error. Thank you! By the way, to access classes with space you used dot(.) instead. Is it really how it's done with classes that have spaces?

Comment: actually classame doesn't have any spaces in their name  if you are seeing spaces in classname it means there are more then once class separated by spaces . In your element `class="z-combobox-designation z-combobox"` there are 2 classes 1 = `z-combobox-designation` and 2 = `z-combobox` in css selector `dot(.)` is used to define that its a class